# Parsing a particular string in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, string-parsing, parsec

I'm using the parsec Haskell library.

I want to parse strings of the following kind:

```
[[v1]][[v2]]

xyz[[v1]][[v2]]

[[v1]]xyz[[v2]]
```

etc.

I'm interesting to collect only the values v1 and v2, and store these in a data structure.

I tried with the following code:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

quantifiedVars = sepEndBy var (string "]]")
var = between (string "[[") (string "") (many (noneOf "]]"))

parseSL :: String -> Either ParseError [String]
parseSL input = parse quantifiedVars "(unknown)" input

main = do {
   c <- getContents;
   case parse quantifiedVars "(stdin)" c of {
      Left e -> do { putStrLn "Error parsing input:"; print e; };
      Right r -> do{ putStrLn "ok"; mapM_ print r; };
   }
}
```

In this way, if the input is `"[[v1]][[v2]]"` the program works fine, returning the following output:

```
"v1"

"v2"
```

If the input is `"xyz[[v1]][[v2]]"` the program doesn't work. In particular, I want only what is contained in `[[...]]`, ignoring `"xyz"`.

Also, I want to store the content of `[[...]]` in a data structure.

How do you solve this problem?

Comment: So you want to skip anything not delimited by `[[` and `]]`? `"xyz[[v1]][[v2]]"` and `"[[v1]]xyz[[v2]]"` both should yield `["v1","v2"]`?

Comment: It looks like easy task for regex. Something like `\\[\\[([^]]+)\\]\\]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to restructure your parser. You are using combinators in very strange locations, and they mess things up.

A `var` is a `varName` between "[[" and "]]". So, write that:

```
var = between (string "[[") (string "]]") varName
```

A `varName` should have some kind of format (I don't think that you want to accept "%A¤%&", do you?), so you should make a parser for that; but in case it really can be anything, just do this:

```
varName = many $ noneOf "]"
```

Then, a text containing vars, is something with vars separated by non-vars.

```
varText = someText *> var `sepEndBy` someText
```

... where `someText` is anything except a '[':

```
someText = many $ noneOf "["
```

Things get more complicated if you want this to be parseable:

```
bla bla [ bla bla [[somevar]blabla]]
```

Then you need a better parser for `varName` and `someText`:

```
varName = concat <$> many (try incompleteTerminator <|> many1 (noneOf "]"))

-- Parses e.g. "]a"
incompleteTerminator = (\ a b -> [a, b]) <$> char ']' <*> noneOf "]"

someText = concat <$> many (try incompleteInitiator <|> many1 (noneOf "["))

-- Parses e.g. "[b"
incompleteInitiator = (\ a b -> [a, b]) <$> char '[' <*> noneOf "["
```

**PS**. `(<*>)`, `(*>)` and `(<$>)` is from `Control.Applicative`.

Comment: Dear dflemstr, thanks for the answer very detailed. I tried to implement your solution, but I've a problem of ambiguity importing the library "Control.Applicative" together with "Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec". In particular, "Ambiguous occurrence `many'..." "Ambiguous occurrence `<|>'...". So, I tried to use "hiding ((<|>),many)" but ghc returns a new error. How do you solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: That's how I do it; you can try doing `import Control.Applicative ((<*>), (*>), (<$>))` instead.